# Linux mv file with long name

Tags: linux, filesystems, files, mv

In Linux I sometimes rename files like this:

```
mv dir1/dir2/dir3/file.txt  dir1/dir2/dir3/file.txt.old
```

Note that I want to just rename the file, not move it to another directory.

Is there a command that would allow me to do a shorthand version of that command? I am thinking something like:

```
mv dir1/dir2/dir3/file.txt  file.txt.old
```

or maybe even something like (to just append to the name):

```
mv dir1/dir2/dir3/file.txt  {}.old
```

My goal is not to have to specify the complete path again.

I know those "examples" I wrote don't work, but it is just an idea of what I want to accomplish.

I don't want to have to cd in to the directory.

Comment: Why don't you change to the directory? It is fast and solves your problem.

Comment: I am dealing with many subdirectories from this same location, it is slower if I have to be coming back to this parent dir every time

Comment: Nobody said you had to change to some other directory, only the one you want.

Comment: Note that `(cd dir1/dir2/dir3 && exec mv file.txt{,.old})` has effectively the same performance as the code without the subprocess, because the `exec` avoids `fork()`ing during the external command invocation, so you have exactly one fork either way.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

for a single file try

```
mv dir1/dir2/dir3/file.{txt,txt.old}
```

where the `X{a,b}` construct expand to `Xa Xb`, you can have a preview using

```
echo dir1/dir2/dir3/file.{txt,txt.old}
```

to see if it fit your need.

note:

1. that for multiple files

   ```
   mv dir1/dir2/dir3/file{1,2,3}.{txt,txt.old}
   ```

is unlikely to expand to what you want. (this will expand to a mixed of file.txt file1.txt.old file2.txt ...)

2. `{txt,txt.old}` can be shorterned to `{,.old}` as per comment
3. if directory name are unambigous, wildcard can be used.

   ```
   mv *1/*2/d*/*.{,old}
   ```

for multiple file use `rename`

```
rename -n s/txt/old.txt/ dir1/dir2/dir3/file*.txt
```

drop `-n` to have effective rename.

Comment: nice, I didn't know this way of expanding! thank you

Comment: Would `mv dir1/dir2/dir3/file.txt{,.old}` not also work, and be even shorter?

Comment: @Josh Yes it works perfectly and requires fewer keystrokes. I use this construct very regularly.

Comment: it is funny how you can use the Linux shell for years and still find new tricks all the time

Comment: I guess all those "tricks" would be more obvious if I had had some formal training in the bash language, but I have been just learning enough to get along.

Comment: @santiagoarizti  thoses tricks came in long run, some through forum like this (along with U&L, SU, AskUbuntu ...), and sometime by reading carefully man pages (specially long one like `bash` or `awk`). To be clear I DID find tricks here and I DO find some trick reading man.

Comment: Is there any "backward" command? For e.g. I want to rename file.txt.old to file.txt

Comment: @ALex_hha just use the other way `mv file.txt{.old,}`

Answer (score 6):

The command `rename` renames all matched files. Its main purpose is to rename multiple files, but if the Perl expression matches only one file, then it will rename only this single file. For details and distro specific syntax please read the manpage: `man rename`.

Example usage: rename "/path/file.txt" to "/path/file.txt.old":

`rename 's/file.txt/file.txt.old/g' /path/file.txt`

Shorter notation (thanks to shalomb):

```
rename 's/$/.old/' /path/file.txt
rename '$_.=".old"' /path/file.txt
```

For a dry run use `rename -n`.

More examples and details can be found at https://thepcspy.com/read/bulk-rename-files-in-ubuntu/

Comment: cool, I knew about the rename command, just never knew all it could do, thank you!

Comment: Unfortunately different Linux distributions have different `rename` commands with completely different behavior.

Comment: For this particular task of renaming by appending `.old` to the filename, It's probably a bit more convenient to do a `rename 's/$/.old/' /path/to/file.txt` or `rename '$_.=".old"' /path/to/file.txt`

Comment: @Fabian - I wasn't nitpicking, just aiming for the "shortest hand" for what seems to be a frequently used idiom the OP is looking for :)

Answer (score 4):

I like @archemar's solution of using {} expansion, because you can use it when you have already started your command line. Here are some other possibilities for completeness:

```
F="dir1/dir2/dir3/file.txt" ; mv "$F" "$F.old"
```

(quotes are only necessary if you have spaces or other word-breaking characters in the name)

```
mymv() {
    mv "$1/$2" "$1/$3"
}

mymv dir1/dir2/dir3 file.txt file.txt.old
mymv dir5/dir6/dir7 file.txt file.txt.old
```

Notes:

- This is bash syntax, you might be using another shell
- `mymv` can be any reasonable string, I used mymv for "my move".
- The function definition can be put in your .bash_profile

Another one:

```
cd dir1/dir2/dir3 ; mv file.txt file.txt.old ; cd -
```

but

```
(cd dir1/dir2/dir3/ && exec mv file.txt file.txt.old)
```

(from @Adam and @CharlesDuffy) is arguably better in case the cd fails.

Comment: Don't use `mmv`, there is already a program named this way.

Comment: @glglgl Done :)

Answer (score 4):

For a one-off case, if I want to not change my current directory I might just use a sub-shell:

```
(cd dir1/dir2/dir3/ && mv file.txt file.txt.old)
```

Because you `cd` inside the sub-shell, you haven't changed your directory in your actual shell

Comment: Faster and safer to use `&& exec mv` -- that way you don't try to do the rename if the `cd` fails, and the `exec` consumes the subshell, thus avoiding a performance penalty.

Comment: Agree with the `&&`  For a one-off case, as I said, I wouldn't worry about the cost of the sub-shell (keep it simple: being able to easily remember how to do it is more important IMO)

Comment: I'd argue that if you're going to remember only one way, remembering the efficient way helps make sure you don't go the inefficient route in cases where it *does* matter.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to enter the subdirectory in order to shorten the `mv` command, but want to come back to the current directory afterwards, there are two ways to do that. One is to put the `cd` and `mv` in a subshell (as has already been suggested).

The other is to use `pushd` and `popd` to change directories:

```
pushd dir1/dir2/dir3/; mv file.txt file.txt.old; popd
```

The`pushd` command is like `cd`, except it first pushes the name of the current directory onto a stack. `popd` removes the top name from the stack and changes to that directory.

Comment: `pushd` and `popd` are extensions intended for interactive use -- POSIX explicitly lists them as "results are unspecified", and a shell built for running scripts (ie. on a minimal embedded environment) need not support them.

Answer (score 2):

I would just do

```
cd dir1/dir2/dir3/
mv file.txt file.txt.old
cd ~- # go to the most recent directory
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution involving  : `mv something{.txt,.txt.old}` are using a "bashism".
If you want a more portable way, using common variable manipulations:

```
# rename all files "file*.txt" of directory /dir1/dir2/dir3 into file*.txt.old:
for f in dir1/dir2/dir3/file*.txt ; do
  mv "$f" "${f/.txt/.txt.old}"  # note there are no terminating "/"
done


# "${var/A/B}" is the content of var with the first occurence of "A" replaced by "B"
```

Comment: See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_02 for the pertinent POSIX specification -- `${var/text/replacement}` is a bashism itself.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy oh... You make me sad :(